# I get unreasonable results with math.h (Windows/Eclipse/CDT/MinGW)

Tags: c++, linker, g++, shared-libraries

I'm writting a code on C++, as IDE I use Eclipse/CDT and as compiler I use g++.
This was working fine, but after some modifications, I have got a problem with the header 
Indeed, I get unreasonable results for exp,log and sqrt. (For example, exp(0)=2 or log(1)=17565120)

I have checked similar issue. But as you can see in the log of the build, the linker contain the reference to the library libm.a.

Part of the message in the log :
g++ -shared -Wl,--output-def=definition.def -o toto.dll toto1.o toto2.o toto3.o toto4.o toto5.o toto6.o toto7.o -lpthreadGC2 -lm

So, I don't understand why I get these errors.

Moreover, if I do for example : nm toto.dll | find "exp" I get : "68c0de38 T _exp". So, it lets me think that the function exp has a reference.

I haven't get warning message concerning  during the build and the header  is in one of my headers file which is called by others.
If I do a left click on the "#include ", the file math.h will be open.

What could I do in purpose of determining the origin of my problem?

P.S : I can see reading comment, that my description was not really clear.
The problem appeared using the following formula : -log(at * exp(-bt * rt))/remainingLife
In this formula, at,bt,rt and remainingLife are double. -bt*rt=-0.0011072580657125247 and exp(-bt*rt)=32.
I have just add some example that I get using the expression functionality of eclipse.

P.S 2 : When I do nm toto.dll | find "exp" I get also : "68c2b1ec I __imp__exp"

P.S 3 : When I build with option -E, I can see in each file .o that there is only one line with declaration of function exp, it's  "double **attribute**((**cdecl**)) exp (double);" which come from MinGW\Include\math.h.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try with double values? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/exp/

Comment: Of course, for example : exp(1.5) return me 32 and log(1.5) return me 6.

Comment: Actually, the `T` indicates that `exp` isn't _referenced_ but it is _defined_! You should get rid of this definition and I'd guess your problems get resolved.

Comment: But as you can sse in my previous comment,I get same problem when I use double as input.

Comment: The symbol `_exp` is clearly a non-mangled C-symbol: you call it with whatever you dump into the correct location and it will be interpreted according to its definition. It seems, you are defining `double exp(double)` (possibly with additional arguments and either in a C file or with `extern "C"`) as it seems to yield saner results.

Comment: Independent of your edits, the `T` in the output states that `_exp` is _defined_ (as a function with C linkage; the `T` says it's a function and the missing mangling of parameters indicate that it has C linkage) in your DLL and will conflict with the `_exp` from the standard C library! If the `T` where `U` the symbol would be referenced: the meaning of these letters is easily verified by looking at [`nm`'s man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm).

Comment: I use the following option during my build -Wl,--output-def=definition.def and in the generated definition.def, I can't see any function which would be called "exp".
I'm not overloading this function in the code that I wrote.

Comment: Well, I'm sure you have had a look at [`nm`'s man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm) which clearly shows that there is a definition in `toto.dll`.

Comment: Sorry Dietmar, I haven't well understanding your firt comment. So, if I understand now, you mean that somewhere in my code I use a redefinition of the function double exp(double) and that if I suppress it, it would be ok. It seems weird, I don't use this. Could it be possible that this definition is used in one of the header files that I used :
pthread.h;semaphore.h;map;math.h;iostream;vector;stdio.h;fstream;string;stdlib.h?

Comment: It is unlikely that any of these headers _defines_ `exp` although, clearly, `<math.h>` _declares_ `exp`. I vaguely recall having had a similar problem but I don't recall the cause. I _could_ imagine that something uses a macro which gets expanded to result in `exp`. The best way to detect the use of `exp` in your translation units is to preprocess the files (using the ubiquitious `-E` option for the compiler) and look for it in the result.

Comment: I have checked on files .o, for each file.o there is only one line  which correspond to "exp", this is : "double __attribute__((__cdecl__)) exp (double);" This line come from MinGW/include

Comment: You might have a bug in your code, it would help if you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy, problems come from the utilisation of windows "Expressions" of Eclipse/CDT, it returns wrong results in this case.
Matt McNabb was right,  is not the problem in my code. There is another bug.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the return values from `exp` and `log` to integers. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `T` in the output of [`nm`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm) indicates that your DLL *defines* a "text symbol" with the name `_exp`. It does **not** mean that `_exp` is referenced: that would use a `U` instead. Most likely, this definition interfers with the functions from the standard C library.

The defined symbol clearly has C-linkage as it doesn't include any aspect of mangled functin parameters. That is, it is either defined as `extern "C"` in a C++ file, possibly getting the declaration from `<math.h>` and the definition not using `extern "C"`, or it is defined in a C file.

Comment: Your comment is interesting, but I have launch a search of "exp" in my workspace, I get only one result which is not just a use of the function exp, it's : "_CRTIMP double __cdecl exp (double);" which belong to <math.h>